# Continuous html page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to achieve a continuous scrolling html page.

I've found this continuous scrolling of a `div` example, but I am unable to modify the code so it works on a whole html page:

Here is a jsfiddle of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/N9PWn/

Any help in pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Placing this code here will assist you in getting better responses.

Comment: What you are looking for is a paralax scrolling website. Try googling that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you set the width/height of the div to 100% of the space?

**UPDATE**:

```
#verticalScroller {
    position: absolute;
    width: 52px;
    height: 98%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/N9PWn/122/)**

Answer (score 0):

The naive answer would be to have any content for your page to exist inside the scrolling div.

Answer (score 0):

you need to adjust the width in your CSS.

```
#verticalScroller {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;                       //set the width to 100% to take over the space
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#verticalScroller > div{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;                     //set the width to 100% there also 
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Infinite scrolling?](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)